# Delayed_job custom failing assertions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, priority-queue

I'm using delayed_job for a priority queue. I was wondering how do i define what a failed job is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A failed job is a job that raises an error.  If you want the job to fail you can simply raise an error.  Sometimes, if I am waiting on something else to finish, instead of failing the job I will put another job in the queue with a `run_at` for x time in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Failed jobs are deleted by default, just like successful ones. However, you can configure [delayed_job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to keep them, in which case the failed_at column will be populated with the time of the last failure. Then you simply check if failed_at is nil or not. With the default behaviour, I haven't found a way to tell a successful job from a failed one.

Comment: Oops, I reread the question and can see that I'm not really answering it. Luckily Geoff nailed it!